# How to prevent bunnies eating my plants?

Tags: pests

Bunnies are eating all my flowering  plants. Is there a repellent that works best with bunnies? or what can I do to prevent them from eating plants?

Comment: Hi RSH! I see you've been to other sites on the network but this is your first post here, so, welcome! Niall C. suggested a site as a duplicate in his comment. It looks similar to me too. Can you check out those answers and see if something is helpful? If not, feel free to edit your question to be more specific!

Answer (score 0):

I found human hair is a good repellent;  You can likely get it at a barber shop or salon. I think eating would also work well. I have live trapped them and taken them > 5 miles away to release , and they came back. ( I had put holes in their ears with an air rifle , an earlier effort to control them).

Comment: Sorry,I just meant I could identify them when they returned. They were eating the bark off of many fruit trees , so causing long term damage.